# Adding nester OR statements in Doctrine 2, Querybuilder

Tags: doctrine-orm, query-builder

I have a one to many entity:

```
User -> OrderPerson
```

A user can own multiple orderPersons.

An orderPerson is linked to Orders and can have multiple orders.

What I want to do is build a dynamic query to deal with this, this is what I have thus far:

```
public function getPaged($page, $count , $orderPersons = null)
    {
        $qb = $this->orderRepository->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->orderBy('c.id', 'DESC');

        if ($orderPersons != null )
        {
            foreach ($orderPersons AS $orderPerson)
            {
                $qb->where('c.orderPerson='.$orderPerson); ***
            }

        }

        $query = $qb->getQuery();

    }
```

Where I am struggling is how to write the line:

```
$qb->where('c.orderPerson='.$orderPerson);
```

I had a read of the documents and I think I need to use something like this but am not sure:

```
$qb->andWhere(
    $qb->expr()->orX(
        $qb->expr()->eq('c.orderPerson='.$orderPerson)
    )
);
```

I am however unsure how to put this into a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one big criticism I have about the D2 documentation is that they spend a lot of time on exprs but most of the time you really don't need them.  Just makes the code hard to read.

Having said that, you don't need OR conditions for your query, just an IN clause.

```
// Join the order persons
$qb->leftJoin(c.orderPersons,'orderPerson');

// Need at least one
if (is_array($orderPersons) && count($orderPersons)) {
    $qb->andWhere('orderPerson.id IN (:orderPersons));
    $qb->setParameter('orderPersons',$orderPersons);
}
```

Untested of course so there may be a syntax error but you should get the idea.